# Extract Macro from HeaderFile with C#

Tags: c#, regex, macros

I am trying to extract a macro-name and the code behind it with a regex and want to save them together in a dic! The header files I want to scan look something like this:

```
#define TEST_MAKRO (ival)    \
{                            \
   somevalue = ival;         \
}
#define TEST_MAKRO2 (ival1, ival2, retval)    \
{                            \
   retval = ival1 + ival2;   \      
}
#define TEST_MASK 0x123 \
```

Now I´m trying to match the #define (without param) and the whole #define till } like this:

```
string makroexp1 = @"(#define+(\s)+[^()]*)";
string makroexp2 = @"define+(.*\\\n)+(\})";

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
string temporarystring = "";
foreach (string line in lines)
{
   temporarystring += line;
   temporarystring += "\n";
}
foreach (Match makroname in Regex.Matches(temporarystring, makroexp1)){
   //somehow add to dictonary (this should be the key)
}
foreach (Match replacement in Regex.Matches(temporarystring, makroexp2)){
   //add to dictionary (this should be the value of the corresponding key)
}
```

It actually kinda works (matches) but I cannot find a good way to add them together ... something like:

```
makrodic.Add(makroname.Value, replacement.Value)
```

doens´t work obv :/

- Anyone got any good ideas?

Comment: Combine them into a single expression, each its own named group. Then you can extract both at the same time by name. Or add them to two lists, knowing that the key and value will be at the same index.

Comment: I tried the method with two lists, but the problem is that my exp also matches #define that are not makros (eg masks) and then the index is off :/

else it would work !

Comment: Provide sample of text data with more than one occurrence of each match.

Comment: i added a sample ;)

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: my goal is to save an entry into a dictonary something like .... makrodic.Add(makroname.Value, replacement.Value)

Comment: Is there a reason why to load text file line-by-line and then concatenate all the lines (ouch) together? Why don't you iterate line-by-line as it's loaded from the file?

Comment: What is `makroname.Value`, and - more importantly - `replacement.Value`? Just for the sample text above.

Comment: i thought i need to do this, because my regex matches over multiple lines, so i cannot scan line by line :/

Comment: `makroname.Value`, `replacement.Value` are the values of the regex matches!
eg: 1st match for makroname would be `#define TEST_MAKRO`

Comment: Please check `@"#define\s+(\w+).*\\(?:\s*{((?:.*\\\s+)*)})?"` regex. `match.Groups[1].Value` is the name (`TEST_MAKRO`) and the `match.Groups[2].Value` is the contents.

Comment: omg thanks wiktor this should solve my problem, im new to regex and didn´t thought about the grouping

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
@"#define\s+(\w+).*\\(?:\s*{((?:.*\\\s+)*)})?"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%23define%5Cs%2B%28%5Cw%2B%29.*%5C%5C%28%3F%3A%5Cs*%7B%28%28%3F%3A.*%5C%5C%5Cs%2B%29*%29%7D%29%3F&i=%23define%20TEST_MAKRO%20%28ival%29%20%20%20%20%5C%0D%0A%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%0D%0A%20%20%20somevalue%20%3D%20ival%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%23define%20TEST_MAKRO2%20%28ival1%2C%20ival2%2C%20retval%29%20%20%20%20%5C%0D%0A%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%0D%0A%20%20%20retval%20%3D%20ival1%20%2B%20ival2%3B%20%20%20%5C%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%23define%20TEST_MASK%200x123%20%5C)

Then, `match.Groups[1].Value` is the name (`TEST_MAKRO`) and the `match.Groups[2].Value` is the contents.

**Details**:

- `#define` - a literal substring
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 matching one or more word chars
- `.*\\` - any 0+ chars other than a newline as many as possible up to the last `\` on a line that is followed with...
- `(?:\s*{((?:.*\\\s+)*)})?` - an optional non-capturing group matching a sequence of:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `{` - a `{`
  - `((?:.*\\\s+)*)` - Group 2: 0+ sequences of:

    - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than a newline as many as possible
    - `\\` - a `\` symbol
    - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `}` - a `}`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this gives you a good starting point (needs tuning for one-line macros):

```
        var macros = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var regex = new Regex(@"#define +(\w+).*\n\{([^\{\}]+)\}");

        foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(path)))
        {
            macros[m.Groups[1].ToString()] = m.Groups[2].ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys, my final solution looks like this! (thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew)

```
string makroexp = @"#define\s+(\w+).*\\(?:\s*{((?:.*\\\s+)*)})?";

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path.GetFullPath(....));
string temporarystring = "";

string[] keys = new string[0];
string[] values = new string[0];

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    temporarystring += line;
    temporarystring += "\n";
}


try
{
    makrodic.Add(makro.Groups[1].Value, makro.Groups[2].Value);
}
catch
{
    //Already added
}
```